# openchange provision failure

Tags: python, samba

I am currently looking at openchange because I find it fascinating that there is actually something out there that can effectively work as an exchange server.  I followed the directions verbatim however, I keep running into the same problem:

When I get to the part where I need to provision openchange detailed here:
http://www.openchange.org/cookbook/configuring.html

I am directed to type in the following command:

`./setup/openchange_provision --standalone`

I keep getting the following error:

```
Error: "(53, 'schema_data_add: updates are not allowed: reject request\n')" when adding element:
dn: CN=ms-Exch-Access-Control-Map,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=domain,DC=local
objectClass: top
objectClass: attributeSchema
cn: ms-Exch-Access-Control-Map
distinguishedName: CN=ms-Exch-Access-Control-Map,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=domain,DC=local
attributeID: 1.2.840.113556.1.4.7000.102.64
attributeSyntax: 2.5.5.12
isSingleValued: TRUE
showInAdvancedViewOnly: TRUE
adminDisplayName: ms-Exch-Access-Control-Map
adminDescription: ms-Exch-Access-Control-Map
oMSyntax: 64
searchFlags: 0
lDAPDisplayName: msExchAccessControlMap
name: ms-Exch-Access-Control-Map
#schemaIDGUID: 8ff54464-b093-11d2-aa06-00c04f8eedd8
isMemberOfPartialAttributeSet: FALSE
objectCategory: CN=Attribute-Schema,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=domain,DC=local
[!] error while provisioning the Exchange schema classes (53): schema_data_add: updates are not allowed: reject request
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./setup/openchange_provision", line 90, in <module>
 openchange.provision(setup_path, provisionnames, lp, creds)
  File "python/openchange/provision.py", line 742, in provision
    install_schemas(setup_path, names, lp, creds, reporter)
  File "python/openchange/provision.py", line 441, in install_schemas
    provision_schema(sam_db, setup_path, names, reporter, schema['path'], schema['description'], schema['modify_mode'])
  File "python/openchange/provision.py", line 227, in provision_schema
    sam_db.add_ldif(el, ['relax:0'])
  File "/usr/local/samba/lib/python2.7/site-packages/samba/__init__.py", line 224, in add_ldif
    self.add(msg, controls)
_ldb.LdbError: (53, 'schema_data_add: updates are not allowed: reject request\n')
```

I am at a complete loss as to what might be wrong, I have rebuilt this many times and keep running into the same roadblock.  Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am coming across the same error, did you find a solution?

Comment: No, unfortunately this is not resolved yet. I somehow configured the Samba4 to act as an additional domain controller instead of a primary domain controller.  But I literally followed the instructions verbatim so it is still a mystery to me. After so many failures with openchange I gave up and instead opted for an e-mail server built with postfix/dovecot with a webmail application.  For AD authentication I ended up using PBIS open to link my e-mail server to my active directory domain controller.  This fulfills all my needs.  I eventually hope to get back to this..will let you know when I do.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at output of Openchange, you can find a root cause of the problem:

```
[!] error while provisioning the Exchange schema classes (53): schema_data_add: updates are not allowed: reject request
```

Add the following line to the `[global]` section in your smb.conf to allow schema changing:

```
dsdb:schema update allowed=true
```